# How can hyperledger fabric scale for multi factory production?

Tags: architecture, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, high-availability, consensus

I got a bit confused with scallability for the blockchain technology and hyperledger fabric.

this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.00910.pdf says that they can improve transaction throughput from 3000 to 20,000 transactions p/s.

In my use cases I want multiple factories to produce packages which they should transact into the blockchain. Afterwards the same product needs to swap ownership between the suppliers until it gets to the retailer. This should be done in hyperledger fabric.

My problem is: Considering that hunderds of factories make thousands of packages a day and the products being shipped through the supply chain? How can the blockchain cope with much more transactions than 20,000? Not: shipping between suppliers happens in batches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you have hundreds of factories that produce thousands of packages a day.

According to this paper, they have have improved Fabric to 20,000 transactions per second: `20000 * 60 * 60 * 24 = 1,728,000,000 transactions per day` even if you had thousands of factories, they would have to produce millions of packages a day at each factory.

The global volume of all packages shipped daily by UPS is 20 million, nowhere near the limits of this paper.

Comment: Aah alright that does sound enough thanks. So does that 20,000 transaction get effected by the endorsement policy? Meaning that the more people need to endorse the transacton, the slower it goes?